# передача данных между combobox'ами разных форм

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите как передать данные между комбобоксами с главной формы на дочернюю.

На главной форме заполняю

```
selectDBComboBox.Items.Add(new ConnectionString() { TypeDb = "SQL Server" });
```

На дочерней

```
public FormData(FormConnection fc)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBox1.Items.Add(fc.selectDBComboBox.SelectedValue);
        }
```

Но данные не переносятся, думаю что дело плевое, но всеже

Мое решение:

```
public FormConnection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            selectDBComboBox.Items.Add(new ConnectionString() { TypeDb = "Postgre" });
            selectDBComboBox.Items.Add(new ConnectionString() { TypeDb = "SQL Server" });

        }
```

Метод вызывающий вторую форму:

```
private void createBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormData formData = new FormData(this);
            formData.ShowDialog();
        }
```

На второй форме конструктор:

```
public FormData(FormConnection fc)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBox1.Text = fc.selectDBComboBox.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Покажите метод, в котором вы вызываете дочернюю форму. И что вы хотите передать: весь список + индекс выбранного элемента или только выбранное значение? В WinForms есть масса способов сделать одно и тоже действие, но большинство из тех, что видны сразу и кажутся наиболее простыми - приводят к "костылям" и проблемам при дальнейшей разработке приложения.

Comment: @rdorn private void createBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormData formData = new FormData(this);
            formData.ShowDialog();
        }     Нужно чтобы передавало только выбранное значение

Comment: вообщем получилось сделать, но наверно оно как-то костыльно, решение правил в главном вопросе

Comment: Вечером напишу простой пример как можно сделать. А пока на подумать: отделите данные от контролов и форм. зачем ваши контролы и формы знают о зависимостях в данных? Даже если не хочется разбираться с магией биндингов (не такая уж она и сложная) можно сделать все руками, но данные и их взаимосвязи должны жить отдельно от визуального представления.

Comment: изучайте. Пример расширяем для любых целей если приложить немного усилий и ознакомиться с документацией немного глубже. Также почитайте про шаблон проектирования MVP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала отделяем данные от UI, ибо нечего им там делать. Для этого сделаем простой класс который будет хранить данные для ComboBox-ов. Для примера модель будет предельно простой, расширить всегда можно по необходимости как и когда угодно.

```
class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //научим модель уведомлять потребителя данных об их изменении
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public List<string> Data { get; } = new List<string> {"Val1", "Val2", "Val3", "Val4"};

    private int _selectedIndex = -1;

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get => _selectedIndex;
        set
        {
            if (_selectedIndex != value)
            {
                _selectedIndex = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedIndex)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь воспользуемся модельным классом при создании форм. Начнем с диалогового окна:

```
class DialogForm : Form
{
    public DialogForm(DataModel model)
    {
        var cbox = new ComboBox();
        //ComboBox умеет работать с источником данных для строк "из коробки"
        cbox.DataSource = model.Data;
        //А текущий выбранный индекс придется привязать принудительно
        cbox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", model, "SelectedIndex", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        Controls.Add(cbox);
        var btn = new Button() { Text = "Close dialog" };
        btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, cbox.Location.Y + cbox.Height);
        CancelButton = btn;
        Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

Теперь сделаем основное окно программы:

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly DialogForm _dialog;

    public MainForm(DataModel model)
    {
        _dialog = new DialogForm(model);

        var cbox = new ComboBox();
        cbox.DataSource = model.Data;
        cbox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", model, "SelectedIndex", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        Controls.Add(cbox);

        var btn = new Button() { Text = "Open dialog" };
        btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, cbox.Location.Y + cbox.Height);
        btn.Click += (s, e) => _dialog.ShowDialog();
        Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

Как не сложно заметить, разница, в данном случае, только в добавленном поле для хранения ссылки на диалоговое окно и способе обработки нажатия на кнопку.

Ну и напоследок модифицируем запуск программы с учетом необходимости передать в форму модель через ее конструктор.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm(new DataModel()));
    }
}
```

Всё. Оба ComboBox-а работают синхронно, в чем легко убедиться самостоятельно.

---

Пример предельно простой, чтобы показать, насколько, даже в таком примитивном случае, можно уменьшить количество и сложность кода просто используя доступные возможности, которые казались чем-то сложным либо просто было лень читать об этом.

В коде не используется ни одного свойства или метода не описанного в [документации .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/), более того, там даже есть примеры использования.

Answer (score 2):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void OnText(object line);
    public static event OnText onText;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onText(comboBoxForm1.SelectedItem);
    }

}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{


    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1.onText += Form1_onText;
    }

    private void Form1_onText(object line)
    {
        comboBoxForm2.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: вылетает ошибка Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта, в чем причина может быть?

Comment: В каком месте вылетает ошибка?

Comment: private void selectDBComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            onText(selectDBComboBox.SelectedItem);
        }    в этом методе

Comment: Удали это событие и по новому в дизайнере создай его.

Comment: Удали это событие и по новому в дизайнере создай его - не помогло

Comment: Проверяй весь код, может ComboBox по другому назвал.

Answer (score 0):

может вместо

`comboBox1.Items.Add(fc.selectDBComboBox.SelectedValue);`

попробовать

`foreach ( var item in fc.selectDBComboBox.Items ) comboBox1.Items.Add( item );`

?

Answer (score 0):

Один из легких путей, но не всегда правильный - глобальная переменная. Лучше использовать публичный метод или свойство. 
Другой метод - передача данных в конструктор Form2. Ну а там уже выбор за Вами!